# Как в Dev-Cpp 6.3 включить старую версию компилятора(чтобы он появился в выпадающем списке доступных)?

Tags: компиляция, компилятор, devc++

Как в Dev-Cpp 6.3 включить старую версию компилятора, у меня в выпадающем списке только достаточно свежие.

Нашёл на YouTube видео в котором в этом же выпадающем списке и тоже в версии 6.3 был доступен выбор версии 4.7.1, а у меня такой версии почему то в списке нет.

Может быть где то в настройках нужно что то поменять или при установке есть какая то галочка чтобы этот компилятор установился?